# Deficient limb(s) - (King David vs Messiah?)

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, king-david

Around 2015, I read in a Midrashic source - presumably on Sefaria - that either King David or the future King Moshiach (I cannot remember this crucial fact) would have a problem relating to something called an "אבר חסר" or an "אבר קטנות", which seems like a deficient organ, limb or something to that effect. Whomever it was, then prayed (or will pray) and was/is assured Hashem's help and cure.

Does anyone seem to recall anything along these lines that could point me back to the source at long last? I can't seem to locate this now.